# What is the rhetorical purpose of the phrase: "to be honest?"

Tags: rhetoric, rhetorical-devices

What is the rhetorical purpose of the phrase: "to be honest?" I think it has become a way to indicate that what came before was a lie but the speaker does not want to be direct. On LinkedIn, I see it used by Climate Crisis disinformers to smear posts about global warming.

Answer (score 2):

There will be occasions when people do use 'to be honest' as a modal (veridical) marker, added persuasion that the accompanying statement should be received as the truth. Sometimes this is done sincerely, sometimes by a trickster. The fact that it might just be reinforced duplicity makes the modal usage suboptimal. As a famous authority puts it,

> - *[Don't swear oaths (add modal support).] All you need to say is simply ‘Yes’ or ‘No’: anything beyond this comes from the evil one.*

[[New International Version; BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/matthew/5-37.htm)]

But there is also a hedging use of the expression:

**to be honest** [phrase]

> You can say 'to be honest' before or after a statement to indicate
> that you are telling the truth about your own opinions or feelings,
> *especially if you think these will disappoint the person you are talking to*. [feelings]
>
> - To be honest, the house is not quite our style.
> - I'd rather get it out the way, to be honest.

[[Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-be-honest); emphasis mine]

So, making a let-down more gentle.

There can also be the sense that you are baring your soul to someone, being frank and open, revealing more than might be considered necessary ... a confidence, perhaps a confession:

> **to be honest**: to be frank, sincere
>
> - To be honest, I am not really interested.

[[gymglish](https://www.gymglish.com/en/gymglish/english-translation/to-be-honest)]

Comment: These are the ways in which the phrase could, and perhaps should be used. Sometimes, however, it seems to be simply a filler, used without the speaker trying to express any definite idea by it.